# Creating dict within the dict based on dynamic key(contains the numbers) e.g 'abx.123':'xyz'. Group similar numbers to the Dict and make single dict

Tags: python, json

I have a dict object in which key and value pairs are there. So I want to add the key on the basis of key
 e.g.

```
{'abx.123.a':'name',
'abz.123.b':'address',
aby.123.c':'location',
'abc.231.a':'Postion',
'abc.231.b':'dob'}
```

Now i want to add the key who contains the 123 number to the dict and create a dict within dict. And add the key who contains the 231 number to the dict.

```
Data = {
"arn": "arn",
"description": "Security group for all coporate communications",
"egress.#": "1",
"egress.4820.cidr_blocks.#": "1",
"egress.4820.cidr_blocks.0": "0.0.0.0/0",
"egress.4820.description": "",
"egress.4820.from_port": "0",
"egress.4820.ipv6_cidr_blocks.#": "0",
"egress.4820.prefix_list_ids.#": "0",
"egress.4820.protocol": "-1",
"egress.4820.security_groups.#": "0",
"egress.4820.self": "False",
"egress.4820.to_port": "0",
"id": "sg-080b03",
"ingress.#": "4",
"ingress.1279476397.cidr_blocks.#": "0",
"ingress.1279476397.description": "self",
"ingress.1279476397.from_port": "0",
"ingress.1279476397.prefix_list_ids.#": "0",
"ingress.1279476397.protocol": "-1",
"ingress.1279476397.security_groups.#": "0",
"ingress.1279476397.self": "true",
"ingress.1279476397.to_port": "0",
"ingress.2455438834.cidr_blocks.0": "10.10.0.0/16",
"ingress.2455438834.description": "cluster VPC",
"ingress.2455438834.from_port": "443",
"ingress.2455438834.protocol": "tcp",
"ingress.2455438834.to_port": "443",
"ingress.3391123749.cidr_blocks.#": "0",
"ingress.3391123749.description": "eks-cluster-master",
"ingress.3391123749.from_port": "443",
"ingress.3391123749.protocol": "tcp",
"ingress.3391123749.to_port": "443",
"ingress.439086653.cidr_blocks.#": "0",
"ingress.439086653.description": "eks-cluster-master",
"ingress.439086653.from_port": "1025",
"ingress.439086653.ipv6_cidr_blocks.#": "0",
"ingress.439086653.prefix_list_ids.#": "0",
"ingress.439086653.protocol": "tcp",
"ingress.439086653.security_groups.#": "1",
"ingress.439086653.security_groups.3696519931": "sg-0007a603523411",
"ingress.439086653.self": "False",
"ingress.439086653.to_port": "65535",
"name":"xyz.abc.corporate",
"owner_id": "12345678",
"revoke_rules_on_delete": "False",
"tags.%": "2",
"tags.Name": "abc.xyz.pqr",
"tags.abc": "owned"
}
```

Create a dict who has same number within th data dict.
I want like this. The number should come dynamically in future
e.g.

```
Data = [{
"arn": "arn",
"description": "Security group for all coporate communications",
"egress.#": "1",
{
  "egress.4820.cidr_blocks.#": "1",
  "egress.4820.cidr_blocks.0": "0.0.0.0/0",
  "egress.4820.description": "",
  "egress.4820.from_port": "0",
  "egress.4820.ipv6_cidr_blocks.#": "0",
  "egress.4820.prefix_list_ids.#": "0",
  "egress.4820.protocol": "-1",
  "egress.4820.security_groups.#": "0",
  "egress.4820.self": "False",
  "egress.4820.to_port": "0",
},
"id": "sg-080b03",
"ingress.#": "4",
{
  "ingress.1279476397.cidr_blocks.#": "0",
  "ingress.1279476397.description": "self",
  "ingress.1279476397.from_port": "0",
  "ingress.1279476397.prefix_list_ids.#": "0",
  "ingress.1279476397.protocol": "-1",
  "ingress.1279476397.security_groups.#": "0",
  "ingress.1279476397.self": "true",
  "ingress.1279476397.to_port": "0"
},
{
  "ingress.2455438834.cidr_blocks.0": "10.10.0.0/16",
  "ingress.2455438834.description": "cluster VPC",
  "ingress.2455438834.from_port": "443",
  "ingress.2455438834.protocol": "tcp",
  "ingress.2455438834.to_port": "443"
 },
 {
   "ingress.3391123749.cidr_blocks.#": "0",
   "ingress.3391123749.description": "eks-cluster-master",
   "ingress.3391123749.from_port": "443",
   "ingress.3391123749.protocol": "tcp",
   "ingress.3391123749.to_port": "443"
 },
 {
   "ingress.439086653.cidr_blocks.#": "0",
   "ingress.439086653.description": "eks-cluster-master",
   "ingress.439086653.from_port": "1025",
   "ingress.439086653.ipv6_cidr_blocks.#": "0",
   "ingress.439086653.prefix_list_ids.#": "0",
   "ingress.439086653.protocol": "tcp",
   "ingress.439086653.security_groups.#": "1",
   "ingress.439086653.security_groups.3631": "sg-0007",
   "ingress.439086653.self": "False",
   "ingress.439086653.to_port": "65535"
},
"name":"xyz.abc.corporate",
"owner_id": "12345678",
"revoke_rules_on_delete": "False",
"tags.%": "2",
"tags.Name": "abc.xyz.pqr",
"tags.abc": "owned"
}]
```

Can you please suggest me if somebody know the logic for this?

Comment: Your desired result is not a valid python data structure.

Comment: why? we can create an array of object.

Comment: Yes, you can create a `list`. Your example is a `list` containing a `dict`, which has 3 keys: `"arn", "description", "egress.#"` - this is followed by a new `dict`, which would use this inner dict as a key for the outer dict - which is invalid. Try to enter the whole `Data = [{"arn": "arn"... "tags.abc": "owned"}]` block into a python shell, it will raise a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Christian König already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52773657/creating-dict-within-the-dict-based-on-dynamic-keycontains-the-numbers-e-g-ab#comment92469350_52773657):

> Your desired result is not a valid python data structure.

because your code contains things like this:

```
{
  # ...
  "egress.#": "1", # <-- ok
  {                # <-- not ok (key is missing)
    "egress.4820.cidr_blocks.#": "1",
    "egress.4820.cidr_blocks.0": "0.0.0.0/0",
    "egress.4820.description": "",
    "egress.4820.from_port": "0",
    "egress.4820.ipv6_cidr_blocks.#": "0",
    "egress.4820.prefix_list_ids.#": "0",
    "egress.4820.protocol": "-1",
    "egress.4820.security_groups.#": "0",
    "egress.4820.self": "False",
    "egress.4820.to_port": "0",
  },
}
```

But if you want to completely unfold your data like this (probably not very efficient):

```
Data: {
   "description": "Security group for all coporate communications"
   "arn": "arn"
   "name": "xyz.abc.corporate"
   "owner_id": "12345678"
   "tags": {
      "Name": "abc.xyz.pqr"
      "%": "2"
      "abc": "owned"
   }
   "revoke_rules_on_delete": "False"
   "egress": {
      "4820": {
         "description": ""
         "ipv6_cidr_blocks": {
            "#": "0"
         }
         "prefix_list_ids": {
            "#": "0"
         }
         "to_port": "0"
         "cidr_blocks": {
            "#": "1"
            "0": "0.0.0.0/0"
         }
         "security_groups": {
            "#": "0"
         }
         "self": "False"
         "protocol": "-1"
         "from_port": "0"
      }
      "#": "1"
   }
   "id": "sg-080b03"
   "ingress": {
      "1279476397": {
         "description": "self"
         "prefix_list_ids": {
            "#": "0"
         }
         "to_port": "0"
         "cidr_blocks": {
            "#": "0"
         }
         "security_groups": {
            "#": "0"
         }
         "self": "true"
         "protocol": "-1"
         "from_port": "0"
      }
      "3391123749": {
         "description": "eks-cluster-master"
         "cidr_blocks": {
            "#": "0"
         }
         "to_port": "443"
         "protocol": "tcp"
         "from_port": "443"
      }
      "439086653": {
         "description": "eks-cluster-master"
         "ipv6_cidr_blocks": {
            "#": "0"
         }
         "prefix_list_ids": {
            "#": "0"
         }
         "to_port": "65535"
         "cidr_blocks": {
            "#": "0"
         }
         "security_groups": {
            "3696519931": "sg-0007a603523411"
            "#": "1"
         }
         "self": "False"
         "protocol": "tcp"
         "from_port": "1025"
      }
      "2455438834": {
         "to_port": "443"
         "cidr_blocks": {
            "0": "10.10.0.0/16"
         }
         "protocol": "tcp"
         "description": "cluster VPC"
         "from_port": "443"
      }
      "#": "4"
   }
}
```

you can use the following code:

```
def transformData(data, separator = '.'):
    def insertRecursive(dict_, key, value): # Recursive
        ''' inserts recursively:
            mydict = makeDefaultDict()
            insertRecursive(mydict, "deply.nested.value", 42)
            print(mydict["deply"]["nested"]["value"]) # prints 42 '''
        l, dot, r = key.partition(separator) # partition at first separator
        if dot == "": # if there was no separator left
            dict_[l] = value
        else:
            insertRecursive(dict_[l], r, value)

    def makeDefaultDict(): # Recursive
        ''' creates a dictionary thats default value is another dict with the same properties
            so you can do something like this:
            mydict = makeDefaultDict()
            mydict["deply"]["nested"]["value"] = 42 '''
        return defaultdict(makeDefaultDict) 

    # actual code:
    result = makeDefaultDict()
    for key, value in data.items(): # for each entry in data:
        insertRecursive(result, key, value)
    return result
```